# Android Webview Permission denied error when try to video call

Tags: android, webview, webrtc, android-permissions

I am using a webview to load a url which has a feature to video call. 
When i try to initiate a video call. I get the following error "Permission denied. Please refresh the page and allow access to your camera and microphone" .

[image: Permission Denied]

If i give android runtime permission of CAMERA and RECORD_AUDIO. The video call will be initiated and the video will be transmitted to the computer also. But on the mobile side, I cannot view my video as well as the receiver's video. It shows the getDefaultVideoPoster() only.

[image]

I have already tried using WebChromeClient and WebViewClient but still no luck.

Here is my code:

```
    private WebView webView;

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);


    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            myRequest = request;

            for (String permission : request.getResources()) {
                switch (permission) {
                    case "android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE": {
                        askForPermission(request.getOrigin().toString(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
                        break;
                    }
                    case Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO: {
                        askForPermission(request.getOrigin().toString(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
                        break;
                    }
                    case Manifest.permission.CAMERA: {
                        askForPermission(request.getOrigin().toString(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
            Log.i(TAG, "getDefaultVideoPoster");
            return drawableToBitmap(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_temperature));
            //return super.getDefaultVideoPoster();
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
            Log.i(TAG, "onShowCustomView");
            if (view instanceof FrameLayout){
                FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
                if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView){
                    VideoView video = (VideoView) 
                    frame.getFocusedChild();
                    frame.removeView(video);
                    video.start();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

The above line code worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You should always call *request.grant()* on the PermissionRequest you recieved from the website, after granting the Android permissions. Otherwise the app itself might have obtained the required permissions, but it should then still grant the permission request from the website: [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/PermissionRequest#grant(java.lang.String[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/PermissionRequest#grant(java.lang.String%5B%5D))